# List out the files that has been modified before run the program in java

Tags: java

I have a code that can list out the latest modified file in the directory. Below is my code:

```
//store the file to the list
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(store));
    //combine all the file at main folder and sub folder
    Object[] combine = list.toArray();
    //sort the file according to the date
    Arrays.sort(combine, new Comparator<Object>(){
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
            return compare((File)o1, (File)o2);
        }
        public int compare( File f1, File f2){
            long StartTime = f2.lastModified() - f1.lastModified();
            if( StartTime > 0 ){
                return 1;
            }else if( StartTime < 0 ){
                return -1;
            }else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
    //get the file name that has latest modified date
    files = ((File) combine[0]).getName();
    //get the file date that has latest modified date
    lastModifiedDate = new java.util.Date(((File)combine[0]).lastModified()).toString();
    System.out.println("The latest modified file is : "+files);
    System.out.println("The time for the latest modified's file is :");
    System.out.println(lastModifiedDate);
```

When i modified a file in the directory and run the program, it can list out the file that i has been modified. But when i modified more then 1 files in the directory and run the program, it can only show the file that has the latest modification time.
My question is: How can i list out all the files that has been modified before i run the program?

Comment: You need to define one thing - modified _since when_? ALL files have been modified at some point in time. How do you decide which ones have been modified "recently enough"?

Comment: **ALL** files have been modified. Are you actually trying to list all of the files in order of most recently modified?

Comment: @Vilx- The situation is like this: I modified 2 files in the directory, and run the program, the program should give me 2 files that i has been modified. The above code that i write only will list out 1 latest modified file only.

Comment: @Craig - Yup. As long as before the program has run, all modified file should be list out.

Comment: @Ian Then you are going to list out every files: because every files has been once modified (file creation is going to affect the modify time too right?)

Comment: @Adrian Shum- Yup. Lets said i got a.txt, b.txt and c.txt in the directory. If i modified a.txt and b.txt and run the program, it should show a.txt and b.txt have been modified. After this, i modified c.txt and a.txt and run the program, then it should show c.txt and a.txt have been modified.

Comment: That's precisely Vilx is asking: You want to know what is the file changed **from the last time you run the application**.  Then you got the solution by answering that question: You need to find out what is the previous execution of your app, most possibly by storing the time everytime you run the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an application that you will be running repeatedly, to list all files that were modified since the application was last run, store the last run time of the application in a file elsewhere (e.g. "lastrun.txt").

Then upon startup, retrieve this timestamp (from "lastrun.txt") and compare it with the modified timestamp for every file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the files that have been modified before you started your program, try this:

```
//store the file to the list
List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(store));

//Here we will store our selected files
ArrayList<File> modifiedBefore = new ArrayList<File>();

for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
     File f = (File)list.get(i); //get files one by one
     if (f.lastModified() < StartTime) modifiedBefore.add(f); //store if modified before StartTime
}

System.out.println("The files modified before this program start are : ");
for (int i = 0; i < modifiedBefore.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(modifiedBefore.get(i).getName());
```

Note: You should start variable names with lowercase (StartTime => startTime).